# Is it possible to pass Firebase JSON to a javascript object? how?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with the kimono web scraper. It integrates with Firebase which has the data as JSON. I am using a JS library that converts the JSON to XML. The library (see example below) creates a variable from the JSON file.

```
// Create x2js instance with default config
var x2js = new X2JS();
var jsonObj = { 
     MyRoot : {
                test: 'success',
                test2 : { 
                    item : [ 'val1', 'val2' ]
                }
      }
};
var xmlAsStr = x2js.json2xml_str( jsonObj );
```

**Can I pass the JSON from Firebase to the variable? If so how?**

---

I've found this source: https://codepen.io/adamaoc/post/introduction-to-firebase

It shows the approach below, but by itself it does not work.

```
var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://app-name.firebaseio.com/");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FirebaseDB is a JSON tree, and you can get snapshots of portions of the tree as a JS object.

I have found the documentation for FirebaseDB for my own project using a FirebaseDB in the past. If you have not yet initialized a connection to your FirebaseDB, I suggest taking a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

Then set a reference to the place in the tree you want to retrieve the data from.

Here is an example

```
 var database = firebase.database();
 var ref = database.ref("where in the tree you are referencing");
 ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
     YOUR_VARIABLE_HERE = snapshot.val();
 });
```

This is just an example of what you might want to do. Play with Firebase until you are able to retrieve the data you want.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right path. I'll update this comment once I make progress.